# Не устанавливается MySQL. Ошибка при обработке пакета

Tags: mysql, debian

Есть физический сервер с Debian 9.
Нужно установить Lemp. Сервер nginx, mysql и последнюю версию PHP.
С MySQL начались проблемы.
При попытке установить mysql-server, он убедительно выдавал MariaDB. Мне же нужен MySQL 5.7.
Вычитал в интернете, мол надо скачать deb покет и поставить.

Скачал отсюда:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Вышел файл:

```
mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

Установил:

```
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

Потом:

```
sudo aptitude update
```

И наконец:

```
sudo aptitude install mysql-server
```

А во время установки мне выдало:

```
июн 23 16:28:47 ryzhikov systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed s…te. 
июн 23 16:28:47 ryzhikov systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'e…e'. 
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full. 
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета mysql-community-server (--configure): 
подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1 
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет mysql-server: 
mysql-server зависит от mysql-community-server (= 5.7.22-1debian9), однако: 
Пакет mysql-community-server пока не настроен. 

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета mysql-server (--configure): 
проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным 
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки: 
mysql-community-server 
mysql-server
```

И как сие исправить?

Comment: *Мне же нужен MySQL 5.7* ­— исходя из всего вышеизложенного — нет, не нужен.

Comment: рекомендация: удалите весь мусор, который вы натащили в систему: `$ sudo apt purge mysql-apt-config mysql-community-server mysql-server`, а затем поставьте mysql-сервер: `$ sudo apt install mariadb-server`